# Selecting minimum and max column values hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have a query

```
select
  title, id, min(sleep) as min_sleep, max(sleep) as max_sleep
from
  myTable
group by
  title, id
```

I get results that look like this

```
title             id            min_sleep               max_sleep
Sheep             123           11/05/2014 18:03        11/05/2014 18:03
Sheep             444           11/05/2014 12:23        11/05/2014 12:23
Sheep             444           11/06/2014 12:00        11/06/2014 12:00
Sheep             444           11/05/2014 17:23        11/05/2014 17:23
Sheep             444           12/31/2014 19:55        12/31/2014 19:55
```

For each unique id I want it to have one column for the min and max so the desire output should look like

```
title             id            min_sleep               max_sleep
sheep             123           11/05/2014 18:03        11/05/2014 18:03  
Sheep             444           11/05/2014 12:23        12/31/2014 19:55
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but your query should already return the desired output. Maybe there are some trailing spaces within the titles?

Comment: My query is not returning my desired output, it is returning all the records and not selecting distinct id's, with min and max

Comment: You should be grouping primarily by ID for desired output.

select
  title, id, min(sleep) as min_sleep, max(sleep) as max_sleep
from
  myTable
group by
  id

Comment: Your query is already grouping by title and id. It should therefore return a single row for each title/id. I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: Check the column title, maybe you have some trailing space, or case differences

Comment: I figured it out i had to switch the order of the columns in my group by column. Thanks for all the input.